# MFMailComposeViewController dismiss right after presented

Tags: ios, objective-c, email, uiviewcontroller

It works fine on iPhone, this issue only occurred on iPad(iOS7). so weird.

I got this error log:

> _serviceViewControllerReady:error: Error Domain=_UIViewServiceInterfaceErrorDomain Code=0 "The operation couldn’t be completed. (_UIViewServiceInterfaceErrorDomain error 0.)"

I did some search and some answers said that it may have something to do with customized UINavigationBar appearance.

In my case, I'm using a navigation controller and change its color and status bar color

in info.plist: `set View controller-based status bar appearance` as `NO`

then in appDelegate

```
[[UIApplication sharedApplication] setStatusBarStyle:UIStatusBarStyleLightContent];
```

I tried comment that line and the issue still exist. So I don't think that's the problem.

Here is my send email code and delegate

```
Class mailClass = (NSClassFromString(@"MFMailComposeViewController"));
if (mailClass != nil) {
    if ([mailClass canSendMail]) {
        MFMailComposeViewController *mailPicker = [[MFMailComposeViewController alloc] init];
        mailPicker.mailComposeDelegate = self;
        NSString *emailbody = @"";
        [mailPicker setSubject: subject];
        NSArray *toRecipients = [NSArray arrayWithObject: recipient];
        [mailPicker setToRecipients: toRecipients];
        [mailPicker setMessageBody:emailbody isHTML:NO];
        [self presentViewController:mailPicker animated:YES completion:nil];
    } 
} 

- (void)mailComposeController:(MFMailComposeViewController *)controller
      didFinishWithResult:(MFMailComposeResult)result error:(NSError *)error {
    [self dismissViewControllerAnimated:YES completion:nil];
}
```

Comment: i dont see any issue with following code, may be some cached data is xcode make this happen, try restarting both xcode & your device.

Comment: Were you able to solve this issue, by any chance? I'm facing the same issue, and any input from your side would be appreciated.

Comment: It turns out I was using a jailbroken ipad and the mail app is somehow damaged. not sure if this is your case.